# Multiple variable differential equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the general solution to the following differential equation.

$\frac{dy}{dx}  =  \frac{4y}{3x}$

For this question I got the solution $y = Ce^{(4/3)^x}$ but this is some how incorrect. How? What is the right answer? Could someone show me their formatting so that I know where I went wrong?

Comment: Written under the form $dy/y=(4/3)dx/x$, you get $\ln|y|=(4/3)\ln|x|+\ln K$ with $K>0$. Thus  $\ln|y|=\ln(K|x|^{4/3}) \ \implies \ y=Kx^{4/3}$ dropping the positivity constraint on $K$. No need to use exponential function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a separable equation.  So, lets separate.

$\frac {dy}{4y} = \frac {dx}{3x}\\
\frac 14 \ln y = \frac 13 \ln x  + c\\
\ln y = \frac 43 \ln x  + c\\
\ln y = \ln x^{\frac 43} + c\\
y = (e^{\ln x^\frac 43})(e^c)\\
y = c x^{\frac 43}$

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Separable ODE](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx). To separate the variables, divide both sides by $y$.
$$\frac{1}{y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4}{3x}$$
Now, integrate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$\int \frac{1}{y}~dy=\frac{4}{3}\cdot \int \frac{1}{x}~dx$$
Integrating gives:
$$\ln|y|=\frac{4}{3}\ln|x|+C$$
Did you get here so far? If not, do you see your mistake?